# Как сделать универсальный mock для проверки получаемых парамеров?

Tags: python, pytest, mock

Мне нужно протестировать ряд функций func1, func2 и т.д., которые немного схожи по структуре и все взывают в конце функцию execute.
Я хочу проверить, что эти функции возвращают верный результат и что они формируют верные параметры передаваемые в execute.
Путём мока функции execute я возвращаю нужный результат, и там же в моке получаю параметры.

Как мне сделать универсальный мок, может быть в виде фикстуры, чтобы не дублировать его код во всех тестируемых функциях?
Основной вопрос - как получить фактические тестируемые параметры.

Пример я очень упростил - в реальности в фунциях бывают ветвления и поэтому тесты отличаются.
Здесь из-за упрощения, тесты 1 и 2 отличаются только этим: func1 и func2, 'param1' и 'param2'

```
def func1():
    return execute('param1')

def func2():
    return execute('param2')
        
def test_1(monkeypatch):
    actual_param = ''

    def mock_(param):
        nonlocal actual_param
        actual_param = param
        return True

    monkeypatch.setattr('execute', mock_)

    assert func1() == True
    assert actual_param == 'param1'
    
def test_2(monkeypatch):
    actual_param = ''

    def mock_(param):
        nonlocal actual_param
        actual_param = param
        return True

    monkeypatch.setattr('execute', mock_)

    assert func2() == True
    assert actual_param == 'param2'
```

Вижу такой вариант решения - переделать функции func, чтобы была еще функция возвращаемая параметры.
И тестировать отдельно func1_param и отдельно func1. Но это не совсем то, и можно ли проще?

```
def func1():
    param = func1_param()
    return execute_command(param)

def func1_param():
    return 'param1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна параметризация теста. Вот вариант без `monckeypatch`, а с использованием стандартного модуля `unittest.mock`, так проще и идет из коробки:

```
# файл f.py
def execute(p):
    print(f'in execute with param={p}')
    return True

def func1():
    return execute('param1')

def func2():
    return execute('param2')

# файл test_f.py
import pytest
from f import func1, func2
from unittest.mock import patch

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "func_to_test,param_value",
    [(func1, 'param1'), (func2, 'param2')]
)
def test_1(func_to_test, param_value):
    SOME_RETURN_VALUE = 'some-vaue'

    with patch('f.execute') as mocked_execute:
        mocked_execute.return_value = SOME_RETURN_VALUE
        assert func_to_test() == SOME_RETURN_VALUE
        mocked_execute.assert_called_with(param_value)
```

Можно вынести и в фикстуру:

```
SOME_RETURN_VALUE = 'some-vaue'

@pytest.fixture
def mocked_execute():
    with patch('f.execute') as mocked_execute:
        mocked_execute.return_value = SOME_RETURN_VALUE
        yield mocked_execute

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "func_to_test,param_value",
    [(func1, 'param1'), (func2, 'param2')]
)
def test_1(func_to_test, param_value, mocked_execute):
    assert func_to_test() == SOME_RETURN_VALUE
    mocked_execute.assert_called_with(param_value)
```

Comment: assert_called_with - это наверное то что нужно. Единственное если параметр является списком, то сравнение не показывает детально какие элементы изменились.

Comment: тут ответили по сравнение списков  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373990/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-mock-assert-called-with-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2