# Как в mock.assert_called_with сделать читабельное сравнение списков?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, mock, assertion

Как сделать, чтобы при вызове assert_called_with(param) выдавался читабельный результат, если param - это список? Чтобы было видно, какие именно элементы списка различаются.

**Пример:**

```
from unittest.mock import patch
    
def func1(param):
    pass

def test1():

    with patch('test1.func1') as mock1:
        func1(['a', 'b'])
        mock1.assert_called_with(['f', 'b'])

pytest test1.py
```

*Вывод нечитабельный.* При большом списке будет сложно глазами увидеть отличия:

```
Expected: func1(['f', 'b'])
Actual: func1(['a', 'b'])
```

**1. Пример читабельного результата:**

```
def test_1():
    assert ['a', 'b'] == ['f', 'b']

pytest test1.py
```

Вывод:

```
At index 0 diff: 'a' != 'f'
```

**2. Пример читабельного результата:**

```
from unittest import TestCase

TestCase().assertListEqual(['a', 'b'], ['f', 'b'])
```

Вывод:

```
First differing element 0:
'a'
'f'
```

Comment: Как по моему, но здесь все нечитабельно, но первый 'нечитабельный' результат самый читабельный.

Comment: @FotonPC я акцентировал, что если списки будут большими и элементы не такими короткими, то это не будет читаться. Это просто пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вытащить из `mock` информацию о самом вызове как объект (или список всех  вызовов), и делать проверку не в unittest стиле (через вызов метода), а в pytest стиле (через assert). В результате сравнение объектов и отображение разницы будет происходить средствами pytest, а не модуля unittest.mock.

Примеры:

```
from unittest.mock import call

...

assert mock1.call_args == call(['f', 'b'])  # Проверяем аргументы последнего вызова
assert mock1.call_args.args == (['f', 'b'],)  # Проверяем позиционные аргументы (для проверки именованных параметров нужно использовать kwargs)
assert mock1.call_args_list == [call(['f', 'b'])]  # Проверяем все вызовы и все их аргументы
```

Первый вариант по какой-то причине выдает такой текст:

```
>           assert mock1.call_args == call(['f', 'b'])
E           AssertionError: assert call(['a', 'b']) == call(['f', 'b'])
E             (pytest_assertion plugin: representation of details failed: /home/insolor/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/util.py:417: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).
E              Probably an object has a faulty __repr__.)
```

Но второй и третий варианты успешно выдают более-менее читаемое отображение:

```
>           assert mock1.call_args.args == (['f', 'b'],)
E           AssertionError: assert (['a', 'b'],) == (['f', 'b'],)
E             At index 0 diff: ['a', 'b'] != ['f', 'b']
E             Use -v to get the full diff
```

```
>           assert mock1.call_args_list == [call(['f', 'b'])]
E           AssertionError: assert [call(['a', 'b'])] == [call(['f', 'b'])]
E             At index 0 diff: call(['a', 'b']) != call(['f', 'b'])
E             Use -v to get the full diff
```

Если добавить ключ `-v` при запуске pytest, то прямо стрелкой укажет на отличающийся элемент:

```
>           assert mock1.call_args.args == (['f', 'b'],)
E           AssertionError: assert (['a', 'b'],) == (['f', 'b'],)
E             At index 0 diff: ['a', 'b'] != ['f', 'b']
E             Full diff:
E             - (['f', 'b'],)
E             ?    ^
E             + (['a', 'b'],)
E             ?
```

```
>           assert mock1.call_args_list == [call(['f', 'b'])]
E           AssertionError: assert [call(['a', 'b'])] == [call(['f', 'b'])]
E             At index 0 diff: call(['a', 'b']) != call(['f', 'b'])
E             Full diff:
E             - [call(['f', 'b'])]
E             ?         ^
E             + [call(['a', 'b'])]
E             ?
```

Документация: [unittest.mock начиная с Mock.call_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется как-то так:

```
def difference(list1, list2):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list1) and i < len(list2):
        print(list1[i], list2[i], 'не равно' if list1[i] != list2[i] else 'ok')
        i += 1
    if i < len(list1):
        while i < len(list1):
             print(list1[i], '    не равно')
             i += 1
    if i < len(list2):
        while i < len(list2):
             print('   ', list2[i], ' не равно')
             i += 1
difference([12, 5, 4], [12, 5])
```

Вывод будет такой:

```
12 3 не равно
5 5 ok
4   не равно
```

Еще это можно сделать как-то так:

```
missing_in_list2 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2] 
missing_in_list1 = [x for x in list2 if x not in list1] 

assert len(missing_in_expected) == 0
assert len(missing_in_actual) == 0
```